# mysql search returning entire table

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am using this PHP to execute a search, but it's returning everything from the table, not anything related to the search...I am also getting an error with "mysqli_real_escape_string", but I am not sure if it's related.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("***","***","***","***");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Search results</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $query = $_GET['query']; 
    // gets value sent over search form

    $min_length = 3;
    // you can set minimum length of the query if you want

    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
        // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

        $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($query);
        // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

        $raw_results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test_table
            WHERE ('email' LIKE '%".$query."%') OR ('pw' LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysqli_error());

        if(mysqli_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

            echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>pw</th>
            </tr>";

            while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results)){
            // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

                echo "<tr><td>".$results['email']."</td><td>".$results['pw']."</td></tr>";
                //echo "<p><h3>".$results['email']."</h3>".$results['pw']."<br/>".$results['ID']."</p>";

            }

        }
        else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "No results";
        }

    }
    else{ // if query length is less than minimum
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is incorrect. You should be using backticks, not quotes

```
$raw_results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test_table
        WHERE (`email` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`pw` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or
die(mysqli_error());
```

Also, mysqli_real_escape_string requires the first parameter to be $con

```
$query = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE ('email' LIKE '%".$query."%') OR ('pw' LIKE '%".$query."%')"
```

You're escaping your column names wrong, they should be escaped with backticks, not single quotes;

```
 'email'  -- the string "email".
 `email`  -- the column "email".
```

In other words, it should likely be;

```
WHERE (`email` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`pw` LIKE '%".$query."%')"
```

As a side note, you'd be better off using parameterised queries than building the query as a string using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. It's better for security, and it makes the queries cachable for the database.

If you're going to use it with the procedural type call anyway (as you do), you need to pass it the connection as a first parameter;

```
$query = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $query);
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it...as far as parameterised queries instead of the escape string, do you have any suggested reading for me to learn how to do this?

Comment: @user1958605 [This](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/54239-introduction-to-mysqli-and-prepared-statements/) is a fairly decent quick start that shows the different styles of doing queries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote your query differently. Try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE (`email` LIKE '%" . $query . "%') OR (`pw` LIKE '%" . $query . "%')"
```

Also your mysqli_real_escape_string needs the $con in it like:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $query)
```